# How to find any element x of a set A, with three subsets B, C and D, by asking only three questions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, computer-science

The main set A = {s, w, p, n, l, d, c, **b**} has three subsets B, C and D.

B = {s, l, n, d}

C = {s, p, l, c}

D = {w, s, n, c}

Only three yes/no questions are required to find any element x. I don't understand how this is possible since the questions could vary depending on if the answer to a previous question is yes or no.

Comment: Hint:  given three subsets, there are $8$ possible cases for each element of $x\in A$, ($x$ could be in none of the subsets, just the first one, just the second and third, and so on).

Answer (score 2):

The three questions are:

1. Is $x$ in $B$?
2. Is $x$ in $C$?
3. Is $x$ in $D$?

If the answers are $\star\star\star$ the element is $\star$:

YYY, $s$

YYN, $l$

YNY, $n$

YNN, $d$

NYY, $c$

NYN, $p$

NNY, $w$

NNN, $b$

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb. I was totally thinking about it the wrong way. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: By the way, you could visualize the answer by carefully drawing a Venn diagram.

Comment: I actually did set up a Venn diagram at first, but after staring at it for 20+ minutes I kind of just gave up.